# Query Database through Javascript / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I am having trouble trying to return results from a PHP script, back into my HTML / Jquery application.

Currently, I am trying to connect to the server like so:

```
function getDatabaseRows()
{           
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("POST", "myDomain.com/subDirectory/getRowCounts.php", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

With my response handler being:

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{   
    alert(response.length);

    if(response.length != 0)
        maxArray = JSON.parse(response);

    storage.set('currentID', maxArray);
}
```

Currently, whenever I run the code, `getDatabaseRows()` always ends up calling `HandleResponse(response)`. The problem is that `response.length` always equals `0`.

The PHP script is simply collecting the maximum row count from the database and returning the row counts:

```
<?php

   $rowCounts = [];

   $dbhost = 'host';
   $dbuser = 'host';
   $dbpass = 'host';

   $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
   mysql_select_db("host") or die(mysql_error());

   $sql = "SELECT MAX(TID) AS MaxTID FROM TransData";
   $results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
   $transRow = mysql_fetch_array($results);
   $maxTrans = $transRow['MaxTID'];

   $sql = "SELECT MAX(FID) AS MaxFID FROM FullData";
   $results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
   $fullRow = mysql_fetch_array($results);
   $maxFull = $fullRow['MaxFID'];

   $sql = "SELECT MAX(SID) AS MaxSID FROM SalamanderData";
   $results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
   $salamanderRow = mysql_fetch_array($results);
   $maxSal = $salamanderRow['MaxSID'];

   $sql = "SELECT MAX(OID) AS MaxOID FROM OthersData";
   $results = mysql_query($sql, $con);
   $othersRow = mysql_fetch_array($results);
   $maxOther = $othersRow['MaxOID'];

   array_push($rowCounts, $maxTrans, $maxFull, $maxSal, $maxOther);

   echo json_encode($rowCounts);

   mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I point my browser directly to the script, it echo's the row counts correctly for me. I am only having trouble trying to get data through AJAX.

EDIT:

Ok, I finally got the script connected, it had something to do with Cross-Domain scripting problems. All sorted out now.

New problem though:

```
function HandleResponse(response)
{   

    if(response.length != 0)
        maxArray = JSON.parse(response);

    storage.set('currentID', maxArray);
}
```

HandleResponse throws an error when parsing the JSON `Error trying to parse '<'`, So I assume that it has something to do with the way that Array was encoded. How do I go about troubleshooting this problem and figuring out how to parse that array?

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the following connection method.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

This will solve all your issues and clean up your code

This is a sample of one of my old codes

```
    $.ajax({
        data: "id=" + value,
        type: "POST",
        url: "unlock.php",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1 || data == true) {
                var result = true;
            } else {
                var result = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ - "load data from the server using a HTTP GET request." I think he's using POST.

Comment: yeah...writing your own javascript ajax calls is masochistic

Comment: you talk about `jQuery.get` then you use `$.ajax`

Comment: @samura He isn't sending any POST data, so a GET is equivalent.

Comment: Yes it could, the reason I want to get POST working is for a later AJAX call, where I have to dump a database to the server. Larger file = use POST.

Comment: And I also attempted using `$.ajax` earlier, and it still failed in the same way. Always came back with a fail response and never a success.

Comment: If you have a test page live I would be happy to help trouble shoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest jQuery JavaScript I could get it down to (this uses the GET method):

```
function getDatabaseRows()
{           
  $.getJSON('myDomain.com/subDirectory/getRowCounts.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

And some enhancements to your PHP using a `foreach {}` and `mysql_result()`, although you may want to look into PHP's `mysqli` class for a more future-proof solution.

```
$rowCounts = array();

$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'host';
$dbpass = 'host';
$dbase  = 'host';

$fields = array(
    'MaxTID' => array('tab' => 'TransData',      'col' => 'TID'),
    'MaxSID' => array('tab' => 'FullData',       'col' => 'SID'),
    'MaxFID' => array('tab' => 'SalamanderData', 'col' => 'FID'),
    'MaxOID' => array('tab' => 'OthersData',     'col' => 'OID')
  );

$con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbase, $con) or die(mysql_error());

foreach ($fields as $id => $info) {
  $sql = "SELECT MAX({$info['col']}) FROM {$info['tab']}";
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
  if (!$result) die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
  $rowCounts[$id] = mysql_result($result, 0);
}

echo json_encode($rowCounts);

mysql_close($con);
```

This code worked on a GoDaddy hosted site. For the record, this is my first Stack Overflow answer. Please advise :)

Comment: If you need to use POST `$.ajax( {url: 'myDomain.com/subDirectory/getRowCounts.php', type: "POST", dataType: 'json', success: function(data) { console.log(data); } } );` will do the same thing as above, but with POST instead of GET.

Comment: Obviously don't forget your `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` in the `<head>`.

Comment: Check my Edit on the question

Comment: @Brendan Can you show me the data string that's being spit back by `getRowCounts.php`? For example, my test script returns `["63184","134187","186314"]`. I'm getting no such problems in `HandleResponse()` when testing your code. Could there be a problem with the `storage.set()` call?

Comment: It ended up being a problem with how I was trying to view the webpage / files. I was on a share drive and was viewing the files through `file:////` instead of `http://`